# How to change sidebar navbar color in SBAdmn bootstrap theme

Tags: colors, sidebar

I'm using SBAdmin bootstrap theme in my project https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/

It's all good but i need to change background color of sidebar navbar nav item

[image]

What i've tryed:

Change color in this file Style/sccc/_navbar,
/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css but unsuccesful

Answer (score 2):

> **Changing css of bootstrap is not a good thing.**
>
> It's better to add a separate style sheet and override styles as you want.

```
.sidebar{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

- Add above css to change background color of sidebar.
- You can change background color by replacing "gray" with any color code you
  want.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to remove class type in bootstrap like this

[image]